# Get value of dialog

Tags: android

I have a class to custom dialog, I need to know what values was clicked on this class when dimiss and use it on my activity. How can I do it?.
This is the code:

```
public class ViewDialog {
public void showDialog(final Activity activity, String msg, String idFriend){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_friends);
    String info; 

    TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_dialog);
    text.setText(msg);

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_btn1);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           info = "Button 1";
        }
    });

Button dialogButton2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.my_btn2);
    dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           info = "Button 2";
        }
    });
}
```

}

And call on activity:

```
ViewDialog alert = new ViewDialog();
    alert.showDialog(this, "Test", item.getFriendIconeRid());
     //show value of info String
```

Comment: what do you mean by **what values was clicked on this class**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You can make some variable in your `Activity`;
In dialog you have a link to your `Activity`, just set `activity.your_variable = "info1/2"`.

**2.** If you need to process click on buttons, you can make some handling method in `Activity`, then in dialog call `activity.your_method`.

**3.** Moreover, you even can make your `Activity` implement `OnClickListener`.
In dialog set your `Activity` as OnClickListener to your `Buttons`.
And in `onClick()` you can find id of incoming `View` (`v.getId()`) and depending on that make your actions.

**PS.** Anyway it is not needed to make `OnClickListener` object separately for each button.
Make your `Dialog` implement `OnClickListener` and depending on `View` id make your actions.